# Extending Abstract Remote Actors and Pattern Matching (ClassLoading?) in Scala

Tags: scala, serialization, abstract-class, actor, remote-actors

I'm implementing some abstract classes that extend Actor and provide some extra functionality [1].  However, pattern matching doesn't seem to be working within the receive statements.  If I send a case object `Connect` from a client to the server, and have a pattern match in the server of the form:

```
println("Starting to receive, e.g. " + Connect.getClass.toString)
receive {
  case Connect => println("Got a connected message")
  case m => println("Got something weird: " + m + " of type " + m.getClass.toString)
}
```

Then the output is

```
Starting to receive, e.g. class ConnectionTest$Connect$
Got something weird: Connect of type class ConnectionTest$Connect$
...
```

The incoming message is not recognized as a `Connect` object in the pattern match even though getClass says it is.  Further weirdness: `m` has the same hashCode as `Connect`, and serializes to the exact same `ByteArray` using `ObjectOutputStream` and `writeObject`, but is not equal to it (using `==`).  My best guess is that the classLoader is somehow behaving incorrectly, but I'm at a loss.

Here is a more complete example of what I'm trying to write:

```
import scala.actors.{Actor, OutputChannel}
import scala.actors.Actor._
import scala.actors.remote.RemoteActor
import scala.actors.remote.RemoteActor._
import scala.actors.remote.Node

abstract class ConnectionTest(masterNode: Node, port: Int) {

  trait Message
  case object Connect extends Message

  abstract class Master extends Actor {
    def act {
      RemoteActor.classLoader = getClass.getClassLoader
      alive(port)
      register('MasterProcess, self)

      while (true) {
        println("Starting to receive, e.g. " + Connect.getClass.toString)
        receive {
          case Connect => println("Got a connect message")
          case m => println("Got something weird: " + m + " of type " + m.getClass.toString)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  abstract class Worker extends Actor {
    def act {
      RemoteActor.classLoader = getClass.getClassLoader
      val master = select(masterNode, 'MasterProcess)
      link(master)
      master ! Connect
    }
  }
}
```

Here's an example use:

```
object MyConnectionApp extends optional.Application {

  case class MyConTest(hostname: String, port: Int) extends ConnectionTest(Node(hostname, port), port) {
    case object MyMaster extends Master
    case object MyWorker extends Worker
  }

  def main(master: Boolean) = {
    if (master)
      MyConTest("localhost", 2552).MyMaster start
    else
      MyConTest("localhost", 2552).MyWorker start
  }
}
```

When I run this program, the output is as above.  The `Connect` message received remotely from `MyWorker` was not recognized by the pattern match in the act method of `MyMaster`.  Even though `getClass.toString` evaluates to the same thing on them, they are somehow not the same.  How can I fix this?

[1] More detail: I'm implementing a framework for a certain kind of parallel computation across a large number of nodes.  In a more complicated case, I'd actually like to replace `ConnectionTest` with `ParallelComputation[Data, Result]` where `Data` and `Result` are type parameters.  Message will also include classes that depend on these parameters, like

```
case object Computed(x: Data, y: Result) extends Message
```

Ideally I'd like a solution that plays well with this design pattern.

Comment: Have you tried akka and their remote actors? 2.0 us looking very good. Can you try case classes instead of case objects?

Comment: Do you know if akka solves this problem?  If I change `Connect` to a case class, I get an exception: `java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.actors.MQueue`.

Comment: [this]( http://groups.google.com/group/akka-user/browse_thread/thread/48a2d6ce25e1aa2d) is a working example of remote actors talking to each other, so yes, they do what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested, but I think you should not put your `Message` trait and implementations (including object `Connect`) in class `ConnectionTest`. You can put them in a companion object. If you put them in a class, there is a distinct object `Connect` for each instance of containing class `ConnectionTest` (and worse in the context of serialization, it has a reference to that instance).

objects `Connect` belonging to different instances of ConnectionTest are different and do not match each other.

Comment: Thanks, that did indeed fix the problem.  However, I don't understand why the instances of ConnectionTest are different.  Can you explain the rules here?

Comment: Equality for `object` is by default reference equality. Which I think is the proper behavior. So has long as there are two instances of the containing class, it is irrelevant that those instances are equals, their contained objects are not.